# Prevent YouTube App From Opening When WebView Is Directed To YouTube Video

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm writing an android app that links to internet videos through a webview.  Some of those videos are on YouTube.  When I link to a youtube video, the YouTube app is called and the video is opened and watched through that.  I want to disable that.
Is there a way to use a webview to watch a video on the youtube website without the youtube app being called?  I assume it's the default app on my phone, but I'd like to override that if that's the case.
Thanks